# WebView with swipe Gesture

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I have a page with its first part containing animations. when the user swipes, the animation goes and a webview appears. On swipe up, the webview goes and the animations again appears. since the webview was consuming the touch, I am overriding the webview touch and passing it to gesturedetector object. But what I really want is the control to be switched between webview and the gesturedetector. For now the gesturedetector works or the webview works but it doesnt work together. Any help?

This is what I am doing now:

```
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            // return false;

        }
    });
```

The gesture detector handles the swiping between animations and webview:

```
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                /* Function to pause the video on tap */
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                    /* On Touch event pressed play and pause the videoplayer */
                    return true;
                }

                /*
                 * OnDown() has to return true for the fling methof to take
                 * place
                 */
                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                        float velocityX, float velocityY) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) with a custom web view..

webView.setGestureDetector(new GestureDetector(new CustomeGestureDetector()));

**gesture detector**:

```
private class CustomeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {      
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if(e1 == null || e2 == null) return false;
        if(e1.getPointerCount() > 1 || e2.getPointerCount() > 1) return false;
        else {
            try { // right to left swipe .. go to next page
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 800) {
                    //do your stuff
                    return true;
                } //left to right swipe .. go to prev page
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 800) {
                    //do your stuff
                    return true;
                } //bottom to top, go to next document
                else if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityY) > 800 
                        && webView.getScrollY() >= webView.getScale() * (webView.getContentHeight() - webView.getHeight())) {
                    //do your stuff
                    return true;
                } //top to bottom, go to prev document
                else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityY) > 800 ) {
                    //do your stuff
                    return true;
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) { // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**custom web view**

```
public final class CustomWebView extends WebView {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyle
 */
public CustomWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyle
 */
public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyle
 */
public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/* 
 * @see android.webkit.WebView#onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int)
 */
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}

/* 
 * @see android.webkit.WebView#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev) || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

public void setGestureDetector(GestureDetector gestureDetector) {
    this.gestureDetector = gestureDetector;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've seen that example . The swipe works but the control doesnt come to the webview. Is there any condition which I have to check for?

Comment: webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

Comment: I don't want the zoom controls. I just want the swipe event to be sent to the gesture detector for it to be handled inside onfling() method.